# Children of the <details> element do not inherit any properties even though the properties are explicitly set to inherit

Tags: html, css

Background: I've used the popular `box-sizing: border-box` global CSS setting and found out that this rule fails to traverse the `<details>` element.

I've distilled the issue into an obvious minimal example. The `<details>` element sets several styles and the child `<div>` element tries to inherit some of them.

I've noticed that inheritance does not work for any style properties (`box-sizing`, `border` etc). As if the `<details>` element is not considered to be a parent of the `<div>`. But than, which element is the div's parent?

Am I missing something, or is this a bug in Chrome?

```html
<details open style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100px; border: 5px solid red">
  <div style="box-sizing: inherit; width: 100%; border: 5px solid red; padding:10px">
    Content
  </div>
</details>
```

[image]

Comment: since it works fine on Firefox, I would vote for a Chrome bug

Comment: I am with @TemaniAfif it's most likely a Webkit Bug, as it broken in nearly every browser besides Firefox. Found this one https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213348

Comment: is there any parent element for details are these both in a separate section?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue in Webkit and Firefox. Unfortunately the only fix i got that sticks, works, and is targeted to just the details element is:

```css
details {
    box-sizing: border-box;

    *,
    *::before,
    *::after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

here, this was the bug according to me,
when you already gave width to the parent and its child is taking it's box sizing property, there is no need to give separate width to child element.

fire fox noticed it but chrome considered the width separately.
try this code and you should be good to go on every browser.

```
<details open style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100px; border: 5px solid red">
        <div style="box-sizing:inherit;border: 5px solid red; padding:10px">
            Content
        </div>
```